# How to add custom headers in getDocument() request of pdfjs

Tags: get, http-headers, pdf.js

Trying to add custom headers to the pdfjs getDocument request.

Based on the [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3852) suggestion have tried to add it.

Even while Debugging it is being shown but I am not sure why it is not working.

Below is my js code

```
var parameter = {
  url: this.url,
  httpHeaders: { Authorization: `password` },
  withCredentials: true,
} 
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(parameters);
```

This is my chrome network request

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is happening, because you've defined the Authorization Header wrongly. Instead of putting the password, you must define the Authorization Type you are using. For instance, suppose you are using Basic Authorization, so the Authorization Header should be:

```
{
Authorization: 'BASIC <BASE64 ENCODED OF USERNAME:PASSWORD>'
}
```

If you are using it correctly, try to verify if your version (PDFJS) has already the patch which has fixed the problem. Just go to pdf.worker.js and verify the object *NetworkManager*. Verify if it has the *httpHeaders* and *withCredentials* properties defined. Something like this:

```
function NetworkManager(url, args) {
  this.url = url;
  args = args || {};
  this.isHttp = /^https?:/i.test(url);
  this.httpHeaders = (this.isHttp && args.httpHeaders) || {};
  this.withCredentials = args.withCredentials || false;
  ...
}
```